# How to turn a string with a valid Erlang expression into an abstract syntax tree (AST)?

Tags: erlang, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to convert a string containing a valid Erlang expression to its abstract syntax tree representation, without any success so far.

Below is an example of what I would like to do. After compiling, alling `z:z().` generates module `zed`, which by calling `zed:zed().` returns the result of applying `lists:reverse` on the given list.

```
-module(z).
-export([z/0]).

z() ->
  ModuleAST = erl_syntax:attribute(erl_syntax:atom(module),
                                   [erl_syntax:atom("zed")]),

  ExportAST = erl_syntax:attribute(erl_syntax:atom(export),
                                   [erl_syntax:list(
                                    [erl_syntax:arity_qualifier(
                                     erl_syntax:atom("zed"),
                                     erl_syntax:integer(0))])]),

  %ListAST = ?(String),  % This is where I would put my AST
  ListAST = erl_syntax:list([erl_syntax:integer(1), erl_syntax:integer(2)]),

  FunctionAST = erl_syntax:function(erl_syntax:atom("zed"),
                                    [erl_syntax:clause(
                                     [], none,
                                     [erl_syntax:application(
                                        erl_syntax:atom(lists),
                                        erl_syntax:atom(reverse),
                                        [ListAST]
                    )])]),

  Forms = [erl_syntax:revert(AST) || AST <- [ModuleAST, ExportAST, FunctionAST]],

  case compile:forms(Forms) of
    {ok,ModuleName,Binary}           -> code:load_binary(ModuleName, "z", Binary);
    {ok,ModuleName,Binary,_Warnings} -> code:load_binary(ModuleName, "z", Binary)
  end.
```

`String` could be `"[1,2,3]."`, or `"begin A=4, B=2+3, [A,B] end."`, or anything alike.

(Note that this is just an example of what I would like to do, so evaluating `String` is not an option for me.)

---

**EDIT**:

Specifying ListAST as below generates a huge dict-digraph-error-monster, and says "internal error in lint_module".

```
String = "[1,2,3].",
{ok, Ts, _} = erl_scan:string(String),
{ok, ListAST} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(Ts),
```

---

**EDIT2**:

This solution works for simple terms:

```
{ok, Ts, _} = erl_scan:string(String),
{ok, Term} = erl_parse:parse_term(Ts),
ListAST = erl_syntax:abstract(Term),
```

Comment: Now that I look at the code, I obviously mixing up erl_syntax and erl_parse formats... still cannot figure out how to do this though (Typical too much bejgli error).

Comment: Yeah, if you compare your ListAST with one made by erl_syntax they don't look that alike :(

42> ListAST.                                                                    [{cons,1,{integer,1,1},{cons,1,{integer,1,2},{nil,1}}}]                         43> erl_syntax:list([1, 2, 3], []).   
{tree,list,{attr,0,[],none},{list,[1,2,3],[]}}
44>

Comment: So I either need a way to make an `erl_syntax` compatible AST out of the string, or a way to put a placeholder to the `erl_syntax` stuff, and replace it after calling `revert()`. Or I am missing something obvious...

Comment: Add to this the following comment from the erl_syntax manual: "This means that all erl_parse trees are valid abstract syntax trees..."

Comment: Nah, I just think its not tagged right, so you are putting in [{cons, 1, ...]] and it is expecting {tree, something} where something is related to [{cons, 1, ...}] somehow :(

Comment: Plan B: I will put `erl_syntax` aside, and build my source using plain string manipulation and `erl_parse:parse_forms`. (At least until I get an answer)

Comment: I think I can help you, but don't have time now. Will try later tonight (swedish time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your EDIT example:

```
String = "[1,2,3].",
{ok, Ts, _} = erl_scan:string(String),
{ok, ListAST} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(Ts),
```

the ListAST is actually a list of AST:s (because parse_exprs, as the name indicates, parses multiple expressions (each terminated by a period). Since your string contained a single expression, you got a list of one element. All you need to do is match that out:

```
{ok, [ListAST]} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(Ts),
```

so it has nothing to do with erl_syntax (which accepts all erl_parse trees); it's just that you had an extra list wrapper around the ListAST, which caused the compiler to puke.

Comment: Thanks Richard! I guess I should have figured this out... :\

Answer (score 3):

Some comments of the top of my head.

I have not really used the erl_syntax libraries but I do think they make it difficult to read and "see" what you are trying to build. I would probably import the functions or define my own API to make it shorter and more legible. But then I generally tend to prefer shorter function and variable names.

The AST created by erl_syntax and the "standard" one created by erl_parse and used in the compiler are different and **cannot** be mixed. So you have to choose one of them and stick with it.

The example in your second EDIT will work for terms but not in the more general case:

```
{ok, Ts, _} = erl_scan:string(String),
{ok, Term} = erl_parse:parse_term(Ts),
ListAST = erl_syntax:abstract(Term),
```

This because erl_parse:parse_term/1 returns the actual term represented by the tokens while the other erl_parse functions parse_form and parse_exprs return the ASTs. Putting them into erl_syntax:abstract will do funny things.

Depending on what you are trying to do it might actually be easier to actually write out and erlang file and compile it rather than working directly with the abstract forms. This goes against my ingrained feelings but generating the erlang ASTs is not trivial. What type of code do you intend to produce?

`<shameless_plug>`

If you are not scared of lists you might try using LFE (lisp flavoured erlang) to generate code as with all lisps there is no special abstract form, it's all homoiconic and much easier to work with.

`</shameless_plug>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Robert. In the meantime I got the answer from Richard: erl_parse trees can be mixed into erl_syntax trees. Then calling `erl_syntax:revert()` creates a clean erl_parse tree out of the mix. My only mistake was not noticing that the result of `erl_parse:parse_exprs()` is wrapped in a list...

Comment: At first I also went for building the source code in a temporary file, and compiling it the usual way. Now I changed that to building an iolist() instead, and use parse_forms on that, so everything is done in memory. Unfortunately I lost some nice features, such as code:get_object_code, beam_lib:get_chunks, hipe:compile, but I can live with that.

Comment: BTW I am just playing around with generating modules from template files, while letting myself use Erlang code inside the templates.

Answer (score 2):

Zoltan

This is how we get the AST:

```
11> String = "fun() -> io:format(\"blah~n\") end.".
"fun() -> io:format(\"blah~n\") end."
12> {ok, Tokens, _} = erl_scan:string(String).     
{ok,[{'fun',1},
     {'(',1},
     {')',1},
     {'->',1},
     {atom,1,io},
     {':',1},
     {atom,1,format},
     {'(',1},
     {string,1,"blah~n"},
     {')',1},
     {'end',1},
     {dot,1}],
    1}
13> {ok, AbsForm} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(Tokens). 
{ok,[{'fun',1,
            {clauses,[{clause,1,[],[],
                              [{call,1,
                                     {remote,1,{atom,1,io},{atom,1,format}},
                                     [{string,1,"blah~n"}]}]}]}}]}
14>
```

Comment: I already tried stuff like this. This simply doesn't work when I put this into my AST built with erl_syntax. It makes `compile:forms()` throw up...

Comment: @Gordon, I extended the example in my question. It works perfectly when I create the list with `erl_syntax`. But replacing it with the `erl_parse` stuff is not working unfortunately.