# Convert a string into a fun

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to get around a problem with file:consult/1 not allowing tuples with fun in them like in this example:

```
{add_one, fun(X) -> X+1 end}.
```

To get around this I'm considering writing the fun inside a string and evaluating it

```
{add_one, "fun(X) -> X+1 end"}.
```

The question is. How do I convert the string into a fun?

Comment: To convert string into a fun, load a joke into it :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
parse_fun_expr(S) ->
  {ok, Ts, _} = erl_scan:string(S),
  {ok, Exprs} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(Ts),
  {value, Fun, _} = erl_eval:exprs(Exprs, []),
  Fun.
```

Note that you need a period at the end of your fun expression, e.g. `S = "fun(X) -> X + 1 end."`.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`file:script/1` almost does what you want - it evaluates a series of erlang expressions from a file and returns the last result. You could use it in place of `file:consult/1` but you'd need to change the format of the file from "term. term. term." giving `[term, term ,term]` to "[term, term , term]." giving `[term, term, term]` - place a single expression in the file instead of a sequence.

Comment: I think this is a better solution. If there is a library function which does what you want then you should use it. Also parsing strings when you don't need to seems a bit off.

Comment: Ahh. I may consider doing that instead. I had my head so stuck in file:consult that I forgot to consider alternatives on that part.

Comment: One extra question though. How can I use records in file:script?

Comment: I don't think you can use records in file:script -- you can pass in a set of bindings, but I think it expects records to be replaced at this point. To use records you'd need to parse it yourself, expand out the records ala erl_expand_records and then run it through erl_eval. Someone should wrap all those stages up into a better file:consult/eval really.

Comment: Yeah I figured. But thanks. file:script/1 was a much better way than the direction I was heading.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that Zed's answer creates an interpreted fun. When the fun is called it enters the evaluator which starts to evaluates the abstract syntax tree returned by `erl_parse:parse_exprs/1` that it has captured. Looking at the fun created:

```
11> erlang:fun_info(Fun, env).
{env,[[],none,none,
      [{clause,1,
               [{var,1,'X'}],
               [],
               [{op,1,'+',{var,1,'X'},{integer,1,1}}]}]]}
12> erlang:fun_info(Fun, module).
{module,erl_eval}
```

One can see that it has closed over the parsed abstract syntax tree as seen in the `env` info, and it is a fun created inside erlang_eval as seen in the `module` info.

It is possible to use the erlang compiler to create a compiled module at runtime, and a pointer toward that is [compile:forms/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html#forms-2) and [code:load_binary/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#load_binary-3). But the details of that should probably go into another stackoverflow question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Here is an example of compiling forms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974236/string-to-abstract-syntax-tree.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using the `erl_eval` **[module](http://erldocs.com/otp_src_R13B/stdlib/erl_eval.html?i=113)**?

Comment: Yeah I was lead to that. However not sure on how to use it. It takes expressions generated by erl_parse but using erl_parse I usually end up with an Expression of a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
2> F =fun(Str,Binding) ->
{ok,Ts,_} = erl_scan:string(Str),
Ts1 = case lists:reverse(Ts) of
          [{dot,_}|_] -> Ts;
          TsR -> lists:reverse([{dot,1} | TsR])
      end,
{ok,Expr} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(Ts1),
erl_eval:exprs(Expr, Binding) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.111823515>
3> F("A=23.",[]).
{value,23,[{'A',23}]}

5> F("12+B.",[{'B',23}]).
{value,35,[{'B',23}]}
```